# Is there a R function to add data from a df and append it to a sheet in excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel, r-xlsx

I have a R code that uses joins from various tables and finally have an output dataframe. I need this to be appended to a new worksheet in excel file that already has three sheets in it. I am on a mac and however I try the library(rjava) that is required for library(xlsx) wont load. Is there any other library (that doesnt need java) that I can use for this?

Edit to add: the existing excel sheet has graphs and charts in it

Comment: Have a look at `openxlsx`.

Comment: Package [`writexl`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=writexl) is written in C and doesn't depend on Java.

Comment: does loadWorkbook work for loading xlsx files with graphs and charts?